# Generic type that can be used with the "+" operator

Tags: typescript, generics, types

In TypeScript, is there any way to describe a generic type that can be used with the "+" operator? Something like:

```
function add<T extends ?>(v1: T, v2: T): T {
    return v1 + v2;
}
```

What should `T` extend, or how should it be defined?

I'd like to be able to call `add()` as follows:

```
add(1, 2); // 3
add("a", "b"); // "ab"
```

Comment: Is there a requirement that both arguments have to have the same type? Or could one be a `number` and the other a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add<T extends (number | string)>(v1: T, v2: T): T {
    return <any>v1 + <any>v2;
}

// Valid uses:
add(1, 2);
add('a', 'b');
add<number>(1, 2);
add<string>('a', 'b');

// Errors:
add(1, 'a');
add(true, false);
add<number>('a', 'b');
add<string>(1, 2);
```